# problem in calling a function converting string to lowercase using c

Tags: c

Below is the c code to kill a window in a versatile way.

When I call it in this way, it shows the message and then got stuck.

```
killWindowsVersatile.exe key ci ever 2 1000 "Super"

...closing window with argument:key,ci,ever,2,1000,Super,
name_key = 2;
cs_ci = 2;
ever_once = 1;
delay for 2 seconds start...
remaining 2 seconds ...
remaining 1 seconds ...
remaining 0 seconds ...
entering ever mode
```

Below is the code of the file:
It kills window either by name or a key word, and can delay for seconds, and can be case sensitive or insensitive. It can also loop the command by itself in a interval time of spacing.

There may be something wrong in the to_lowercase function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int name_key,cs_ci,ever_once,delay;

//the order of function is important! you cannot call something before defined !
const char * to_lowercase(char* str){
    int len = strlen(str);
    char * newStr[len];
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
      newStr[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
    return newStr;
}

BOOL CALLBACK WindowFoundCB(HWND hwnd, char* param){
    char *key = (char*) param;
    char title[256]; // This way, you have allocated 256 bytes for the Window name.
    GetWindowText(hwnd, title, 256);
    HWND me = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && hwnd != me){
        if(cs_ci==1){
            char *p = strstr(title,key);
            if (p!= NULL){
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
                printf("==== close a window by key [%s]: <%s>\n",key,title);
            }
        }else if(cs_ci==2){
            char title_lower[256];
            char key_lower[256];
            strcpy(title_lower,to_lowercase(title));
            strcpy(key_lower,to_lowercase(key));
            //char *title_lower = to_lowercase(title);
            //char *key_lower = to_lowercase(key);
            char *p = strstr(title_lower,key_lower);
            if (p!= NULL){
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
                printf("==== close a window by key [%s]: <%s>\n",key,title);
            }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int dealwithonce(int name_key,int cs_ci,char *argv[],int argc){

    for(int i = 6; i < argc; i++){
        if(name_key == 1){
            HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, argv[i]);
            if(hwnd){
                char strIte[256]; // This way, you have allocated 256 bytes for the Window name.
                GetWindowText(hwnd, strIte, 256);
                if( (cs_ci==2) || ((cs_ci==1)&& !strcmp(strIte,argv[i])) ){
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
                    printf("==== close a window by name [%s]\n",argv[i]);
                }
            }
        }else if(name_key == 2){
            char* aStr = argv[i];
            EnumWindows(WindowFoundCB,aStr);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // argumrnt check
        printf("...closing window with argument:");
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            printf("%s,", argv[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    // argument parse
        if(argc < 7){
            printf("%s\n","you must input 5 arguments at least!");
            printf("%s\n","arg1: [name] or [key]");
            printf("%s\n","arg2: [cs] for case-sensitive or [ci] for case-insensitive");
            printf("%s\n","arg3: [ever] for forever or [once] for once");
            printf("%s\n","arg4: the seconds for delay before start., 0,1,2...");
            printf("%s\n","arg5: the milliseconds of Cycle for ever mode., 1,2,500,1000,...");
            printf("%s\n","arg6+: the assembly of any strings");
            return 0;
        };

        if(!strcmp(argv[1],"name")){
            printf("name_key = 1;\n");
            name_key = 1;
        }else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"key")){
            printf("name_key = 2;\n");
            name_key = 2;
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[2],"cs")){
            printf("cs_ci = 1;\n");
            cs_ci = 1;
        }else if(!strcmp(argv[2],"ci")){
            printf("cs_ci = 2;\n");
            cs_ci = 2;
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[3],"ever")){
            printf("ever_once = 1;\n");
            ever_once = 1;
        }else if(!strcmp(argv[3],"once")){
            printf("ever_once = 2;\n");
            ever_once = 2;
        }

        // delay
        delay = atoi(argv[4]);
        if(delay > 0){
            printf("delay for %d seconds start...\n",delay);
            for(int i=delay;i>=0;i--){
                printf("remaining %d seconds ...\n",i);
                Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        //cycle
        int interval = atoi(argv[5]);

        // ever or not
        if(ever_once == 1){
            printf("entering ever mode\n");
            while(1){
                dealwithonce(name_key,cs_ci,argv,argc);
                Sleep(interval);
            }
        }else if(ever_once == 2){
            printf("entering once mode\n");
            dealwithonce(name_key,cs_ci,argv,argc);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `strcmp` return? (If you don't know, type `man strcmp` and read what it tells you.)

Comment: Read the [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) reference. You need to check the returned value of `strcmp`.

Comment: I change all the strcmp(...) to strcmp() == 0, then the programme does not print anything and exited

Comment: Show you updated code (edit your question). I just tried your code with the simple `strcmp() == 0` modification and it worked fine (although you do need a defensive check to make sure the command is given adequate arguments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcmp` returns a value that represents how argument 1 compares to argument 2 alphabetically. If they are equal, it returns 0 which is numerically equivalent to the `false` boolean. Thus you need to modify your if statements like this:

```c
        if(!strcmp(argv[1],name)){
            printf("name_key = 1;");
            name_key = 1;
        }else if(!strcmp(argv[1],key)){
            printf("name_key = 2;");
            name_key = 2;
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[2],cs)){
            printf("cs_ci = 1;");
            cs_ci = 1;
        }else if(!strcmp(argv[2],ci)){
            printf("cs_ci = 2;");
            cs_ci = 2;
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[3],ever)){
            printf("ever_once = 1;");
            ever_once = 1;
        }else if(!strcmp(argv[3],once)){
            printf("ever_once = 2;");
            ever_once = 2;
        }
```

This way if the two strings are equivalent alphabetically, then `strcmp` will return 0 which will be negated to assume the value of `true` and the program execution will enter the if block. If the two strings are NOT equal, then `strcmp` will return either a positive or a negative value which is equivalent to the boolean `true`. Negating this will assume the value of `false` and the program execution will **not** enter the if block.

Hope this helps!

---

## EDIT:

To help you understand why your to_lowercase function might not be working properly, you have to understand two things about arrays:

1. Firstly, the array contents are not passed to the function. The C language (and thus all compilers/interpreters) only passes the single value of any variable to a function when it is called. In this case, the array only contains the memory address of the first element of the array. That address is passed to the function instead of the array as a whole.
2. Secondly, an array declaration is simply a pointer to the first location of a contiguous set of locations in memory. When you reference the first element of an array you are accessing the first memory location pointed to by the pointer. When you reference the second, third, or even fourth element of the array, you are accessing the locations in memory that are exactly 2 or 3 or even 4 memory locations away from the first element.

So what can we do with this? What happens when we change the values pointed to by the pointer? Remember, when you modify an array, (without intervention of some memory allocation tricks) **the memory locations pointed to by the pointer do not change.** *Only* the values in those memory locations change. This is why we cannot copy arrays by simply typing: `array1 = array2`. All this is doing is copying the pointer in `array2` to `array1`. Any modifications you make to `array2` will have a side effect of also being made in `array1` because they both now point to the same locations in memory!

So if you think you have an error in your `to_lowercase` function, try this modification to it. I cannot test your complete code because my GCC compiler is for Linux, but it should work for you:

```c
void to_lowercase(char *str)
{
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
}
```

**HOW DOES THIS WORK?**

When we pass an array to a function, we are passing the value of the *array **pointer***. Thus the function only receives a location in memory. By utilizing this pointer, we can advance through memory to the other locations pointed to by that pointer (via `str[i]`) and modify them freely without affecting the value of the pointer itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why the if(strcmp(argv[1],name) == 0) does not work

Comment: one is bool one is int, so the type is not comparable?

Comment: you need to look at the [man pages for `strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). "_The strcmp() function compares the two strings *s1* and *s2*. It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if *s1* is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than *s2*._" In other words, it works if you compare it to 0...which I just verified with my own compiler. Perhaps you should update your original post with your modified code so we can see where you might have done something wrong.

Comment: @mendel the `== 0` should work. There's something else wrong with your code you're not showing.

Comment: @mendel see this link https://onlinegdb.com/S1zw_JKyI that shows your modifications working.

Comment: The strcmp has been solved, but there are still some problem with this code

Comment: @mendel see my edit. Sorry if it's long-winded, but I felt it was necessary to encompass the broadening of your question. If you have any further questions, please make a new post for each one so you can get clear and concise answers to those questions and not have them get lost in the shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct - your `to_lowercase` function is doing multiple things wrong:

1. The way this function is currently written `newStr` is defining an array of `char *`, not an array of `char`.
2. You're then returning `newStr`, which is an automatic variable defined on the stack. As soon as the function returns `newStr` is subject to being overwritten by any other subroutine calls which are made.

You could choose to define `to_lowercase` as

```
const char * to_lowercase(char* str){
    char *newStr = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
      newStr[i] = tolower(str[i]);

    return newStr;
}
```

but this means that you'd have to be careful to free the memory allocated in `to_lowercase` each time you use it.

A better idea might be to write `to_lowercase` in such a manner that it changes the string it's passed to lower case in-place:

```
char *to_lowercase(char* str){
    for(char *p = str; *p; p++)
      *p = tolower(*p);

    return str;
}
```

This overwrites the original content of `str` so you'll need to be sure to account for that in your code.

Comment: I didn't even address the fact that declaring and returning `newStr` within a function was essentially returning an address to a location in memory that the program probably doesn't even have access to once the function returns. It's far easier (in my opinion) to just modify the contents of the array directly in a void function and return nothing.